# How can I set an image to the Image control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, resources

I'm doing this:

```
<Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Andromeda" Source="/Resources/64px-Andromedahero.gif" />
```

But it's just not working. :S

Here's a screenshot of the file/folder hierarchy. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Can we assume the xaml file where you are declaring the image is in the root folder of the project? The source path is relavent to where you are declaring the image.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of potential options:

1. Make sure that your resources are set to be compiled as embedded resources.
2. If this is a control library, and you're using this from a separate application, you may need to use a [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx).

Edit:

If it's a control library, you'll want to use:

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/MyControlLibraryAssembly;component/Resources/64px-Andromedahero.gif"
```

Comment: Changed all pictures to Embedded Resource, and STILL it refuses to work. Why is it so dificult to just put a picture onto an image. :D Please help! I'm using this and it still isn't working: Source="/Resources/64px-Andromedahero.gif"

Comment: If this is a control library, you need to setup a pack URI.  I'll edit to explain.